# File Renaming on Ajax MVC Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get the custom file name when files are uploaded using Ajax and MVC. I'm unsure how to get the name that is parsed through the formdata.append method..

**Here is my JQuery code:**

```
  var formData = new FormData();
                var companyCKAttachmentFile = document.getElementById("companyCKAttachmentFile").files[0];
                var companyVATAttachmentFile = document.getElementById("companyVATAttachmentFile").files[0];
                formData.append("companyCKAttachmentFile", companyCKAttachmentFile);
                formData.append("companyVATAttachmentFile", companyVATAttachmentFile);


                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    url: 'registerfiles',
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: regFilesSuccess,
                    complete: resetWait,
                    error: regFailure
                });
```

and on MVC controller side:

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterFiles(FormCollection form)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    string message = "";
                    //  Get all files from Request object  
                    HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";  
                        //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);  

                        HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                        string fname;

                        // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                        if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                        {
                            string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                            fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fname = file.FileName;
                        }

                        message += "filename = " + fname + "   ";

                        // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
                        //fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                        //file.SaveAs(fname);
                    }

                    return Json(new
                    {
                        success = true,
                        message = message,
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //registration complete.
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        message = "An error occured uploading your files. " + ex.Message,
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //registration complete.
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = true,
                    message = "redirect",
                });
            }  
        }
```

When saving the files, it needs to save with 'companyCKAttachmentFile' and 'companyVATAttachmentFile' as the file names.

From the MVC side, I can only get the filename from the actual file and not the name from the formdata.append method. How do you get that name on MVC side?

Comment: Replace `FormCollection form` with `HttpPostedFileBase companyCKAttachmentFile, HttpPostedFileBase companyVATAttachmentFile` (or a model containing those 2 properties). Never use `FormCollection` in MVC)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  With my situation, the user would be uploading many files. They will be adding contacts and for each contact, they would be required to upload ID Docs. so I would need to save that into an array. For a set number of files, it would be better to go with your suggestion I think.